# Eclipse debug: попасть внутрь метода; получить информацию о классах

Tags: отладка, eclipse

Добрый день. 
Не могу понять, при пошаговом выполнении (ставлю точку останова, step into, step 
....) программы пытаюсь попасть вовнутрь метода (который находится в другом файле), в результате получаю: **"source not found"**... Такая же ситуация возникает, если я пытаюсь получить информацию (ctrl+click) о некоторых классах (например класс `button`, нажимаю ctrl+click на этом классе, вместо описания (или вида реализации как в Visual Studio) получаю
**source not found**...
Подскажите, как исправить данную ситуацию?

Заранее спасибо.

Answer (score 1):

Нужно подключить исходники (source) от тех библиотек, просмотр которых ты хочешь получить.

Comment: а если я не могу зайти в методы своих классов(по F6)?